MainActor in Task
Hi I have been trying to wrap my head around the usage @MainActor in a Task, as part of Swift Concurrency.
If I have a code snippet like the one below:
Task { @MainActor in
      do {
        let imageData = try await fetchImage?.value
        // Update UI here, assign to an image
      } catch {
        self.image = .error(error)
      }
   }

where fetchImage is an async task and I am interested in the value property.
From what I understand, as this task is marked @MainActor, it has the context of the MainActor. So when fetchImage is called, does the call happen on the main thread itself? or is that the call to fetchImage happens on a background thread, it only switches back to main thread once the call returns?

In GCD, we dispatch code to a queue and that dictates on which thread the called code runs (unless of course, the called function subsequently dispatches it to another queue). In effect, the caller often bears the responsibility for making sure it dispatches it to the right queue. In Swift concurrency, if the called function is isolated to a particular actor, that dictates where it runs, regardless of the context of the caller. The advantage of this pattern is that if the called function is isolated to the correct actor, it becomes impossible to have it run in the wrong context.

So, in your example, the definition of the fetchValue task will dictate its execution context, and the @MainActor qualifier shown here will not affect that. The @MainActor qualifier will only ensure that the (omitted) “Update UI here” code runs on the main actor, but has no impact of the fetchValue task, itself.

Bottom line, we need more details in order to answer this question. E.g., we need to see how you declared fetchValue including whether it was defined in a function (or type) was actor-isolated or not. Likewise, if the Task { @MainActor in … } shown above was implemented in a function that was already isolated to the main actor, then the @MainActor qualifier may well be redundant. There just is not enough here to answer your question fully.

Rob explained it well. MainActor applies inside the block, but when you await you can jump to another actor. You can access the return  value from the task by storing the task in a variable and awaiting it (await task.value).

It somewhat depends on what fetchImage is. Should be fairly easy to put a breakpoint inside fetchImage and call po Thread.current though so you can see definitively.
The body of the Task will be run on the main thread but when it calls out to async methods they may or may not run on the main thread depending on whether they are also marked as @MainActor or not.
There's a good related StackOverflow answer here.

async methods do not “inherit” the actor of their caller


TL;DR: Unless you explicitely designated the property (or its owning class/actor) to run on main thread, execution of await fetchImage?.value is not guaranteed to run on main thread.
Long answer.
So lets have a test framework slightly simplified:
class Test {
    var fetchImage = //... TBD
    
    func f() {
        Task { @MainActor in
            print("f is running on", Thread.current) // we will ignore a warning on this line for test purpose
            let _ = await fetchImage.value
        }
    }
}

let t = Test()
t.f()

So what are the cases where you need to await for property value:
Case 1: property is actually doing some async work on get:
class ImageFetcherAsync {
    
    var value: String {
        get async {
            print("async's value is running on", Thread.current)
            return "good bye"
        }
    }
}

class Test {
    var fetchImage = ImageFetcherAsync()
    ...

Nothing here forces property get to run on main thread, and so the result it:
f is running on <_NSMainThread: 0x600001704040>{number = 1, name = main}
async's value is running on <NSThread: 0x60000171c080>{number = 7, name = (null)}

Case 2: your property is not async, but it's part of an actor (which runs on isolated context):
actor ImageFetcherActor {
    
    var value: String {
        print("actor's value is running on", Thread.current)
        return "hello"
    }
}
class Test {
    var fetchImage = ImageFetcherActor()
    ...

Yet again, the property won't be running on main thread (why would it - nothing tells it to):
f is running on <_NSMainThread: 0x60000170c000>{number = 1, name = main}
actor's value is running on <NSThread: 0x60000170e180>{number = 7, name = (null)}

How to make it run on main thread? Simplest is add @MainActor to it in both cases:
    @MainActor var value: String {
    ...

Then of course it will be running on main thread in both cases. In first case you will need await still, but in second case the property will be retrieved synchronously:
actor ImageFetcherActor {
    
    @MainActor var value: String {
    ...

var fetchImage = ImageFetcherActor()
...
let _ = fetchImage.value // not async


Thank you for the explanation. This made things clear.
